# Testing S3 Intelligent Tiering

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How can I test S3 Intelligent Tiering? I need to test if a file is being transitioned into glacier and deep archive storage, restore the file from those archives and download the files. Since Intelligent Tiering requires file to be in 90days/180days, it is impossible to test it in development.

I referred documentation and wrote some code but i need to test it in real world. How can i do this?

Comment: While you can't immediately test Intelligent Tiering, you could simply change the storage class of an object to Glacier Deep Archive and then test your Restore code.

Comment: Were you ever able to figure out how to do this? I'm in the same boat.

Comment: @howcheng No, unfortunately. If you have better luck, please update this thread.