# With Amazon S3 Intelligent Tiering, how do you know which tier an object is in?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/archived-objects.html says:

> When you archive Amazon S3 objects to the S3 Glacier or S3 Glacier
> Deep Archive storage class, or when objects are archived to the S3
> Intelligent-Tiering Archive Access or Deep Archive Access tiers, the
> objects are not accessible in real time.

I understand this, but how can you tell if an object is in the Archive Access or Deep Archive Access tiers? I've gone through much of the AWS S3 documentation and I can't seem to find this information. I'm writing a UI for S3 and want to display either a "download" or a "restore" button depending on which tier the object is in. I'm just starting development on this so I don't have any files in those two tiers yet and I can't wait 90 days before anything gets moved there.

When you do a `list-objects` request, you get the storage class for each item, which comes back as `INTELLIGENT_TIERING`, but it doesn't tell you which tier it is.

A comment on [Testing S3 Intelligent Tiering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65446775/testing-s3-intelligent-tiering) says you can fake it by changing the storage class to Glacier, but I have my doubts that this is an accurate test because Glacier and Intelligent Tiering are two different storage classes, and it doesn't make sense that Intelligent Tiering objects would suddenly change their storage class.

Does anyone have any insight? Thanks in advance.

UPDATE FROM AMAZON: (tl;dr, this is not possible)

> Unfortunately we cannot identify the access tier for an object stored in Intelligent Tiering class the only way to determine the access tier of an object in by identifying the access pattern of an object. The access pattern can be identified either by analyzing AccessLogs or a user can review access pattern using S3 Storage Lens.
>
> Based on your requirement, the best option for you would be to keep Intelligent-Tiering Archive configuration disabled. With this config disabled the objects in Intelligent-Tiering class will not move in "Archive Access tier" and "Deep Archive Access tier". With this configuration you can create a logic in your application that if the object is in class "Intelligent-Tiering" then the download button will be enabled and user will be able to download the object.
>
> Now for moving objects to "Glacier" and "Glacier Deep Archive" you can configure a life cycle rule. Lets say you can configure a life cycle rule to transition objects in "Intelligent-Tiering" class to Glacier after 90 days and to "Glacier Deep Archive"  after 180 days.
>
> This way using ListObjects API call you can identify the correct storage class of the objects and you can program a logic where the "Restore" button will only be enabled if the storage class is "Glacier" or "Glacier Deep Archive". Appropriately a message will be displayed to users to download the object after 3-5 hours.

Comment: This doc about s3.HeadObject operation gives some hints about archived objects. but it doesnt look like that it exactly tell you where the object is now. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_HeadObject.html

Comment: @ArunK Yes, I saw that too, but it doesn't tell you the current tier. I haven't found anything that will do that yet.

Comment: why don't you create an aws support ticket while investigating this on your own.

Comment: @ArunK Sounds like a good idea.

Comment: thats great. update us if you find out anything.

Comment: @ArunK Reply from Amazon: "Unfortunately we cannot identify the access tier for an object stored in Intelligent Tiering class the only way to determine the access tier of an object in by identifying the access pattern of an object. The access pattern can be identified either by analyzing AccessLogs or a user can review access pattern using S3 Storage Lens." Thus, the answer: this is not doable.

Comment: thats unfortunate. how many files are we talking about. if its few, you can try to download each prior to loading the page with download button. if the file is downloadable, then you can show the download button. its a terrible idea though

Comment: @ArunK I think I have it figured out; if you attempt to do a GetObject for something that's archived, it will probably fail (it fails when it's in Glacier; I'm hoping IT-Archive behaves the same way). In your request, you can specify a byte range, so if I just ask for the first 10 bytes of a file, then it's almost the same as doing HeadObject.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@howcheng You can use [S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/storage-inventory.html) to get list of all of your objects and their corresponding metadata, **including the S3 Intelligent-Tiering access tiers (Frequent, Infrequent, Archive, Deep Archive)**. Amazon S3 Inventory provides CSV, ORC, or Parquet output files that list your objects and their corresponding metadata on a daily or weekly basis for an S3 bucket or a shared prefix. You can also make a [HEAD request](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_HeadObject.html) on your objects to report the S3 Intelligent-Tiering archive access tiers.

Comment: Is that a recent change to HEAD? Because it wasn't available when I was building this a couple of months ago.

Comment: With the launch of the S3 Intelligent-Tiering archive access tiers (link: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/11/amazon-s3-intelligent-tiering-adds-archive-access-tiers/), we added new response (x-amz-archive-status) to see what objects have been archived. 
    x-amz-archive-status
    Valid Values: ARCHIVE_ACCESS | DEEP_ARCHIVE_ACCESS

Comment: Thank you, that worked great. I don't know why your support team colleague did not know about this.

Comment: Happy to help. If you have feedback and feature requests please contact AWS Support (https://console.aws.amazon.com/support/home).

Answer (score 6):

From the official [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/intelligent-tiering-managing.html):

> You can also use a HEAD object request to view an object's archive
> status. If an object is stored using the S3 Intelligent-Tiering
> storage class and is in one of the archive tiers, the HEAD object
> response shows the current archive tier. It does this using the
> `x-amz-archive-status` header.

Example:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-amz-id-2: FSVaTMjrmBp3Izs1NnwBZeu7M19iI8UbxMbi0A8AirHANJBo+hEftBuiESACOMJp
x-amz-request-id: E5CEFCB143EB505A
Date: Fri, 13 Nov 2020 00:28:38 GMT
Last-Modified: Mon, 15 Oct 2012 21:58:07 GMT
ETag: "1accb31fcf202eba0c0f41fa2f09b4d7"
x-amz-storage-class: 'INTELLIGENT_TIERING'
x-amz-archive-status: 'ARCHIVE_ACCESS'
x-amz-restore: 'ongoing-request="true"'
x-amz-restore-request-date: 'Fri, 13 Nov 2020 00:20:00 GMT'
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: binary/octet-stream
Content-Length: 300
Server: AmazonS3
```

Comment: That wasn't available when I originally asked the question.

Comment: Does it answer the question? If so, pls consider voting.

Answer (score 2):

After some back-and-forth with AWS support, I was able to come up with a working solution. For each item in the bucket, I can do a GetObject request and ask for a small byte range (like 10 bytes), so that's pretty much the equivalent of doing a HeadObject request. If the file is in the Archive or Deep Archive access tiers, then AWS will return an exception:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
x-amz-request-id: 43XTDH6Q7E9F2N5J
x-amz-id-2: 3Fn/qzcZwOxaCg1LLDsczSXF7stl7sbOwwDR1ajHIc+guZgxAfFHm1WfRoXWEsFLWPJzKt9Ynaw=
Content-Type: application/xml
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Wed, 23 Jun 2021 16:36:24 GMT
Server: AmazonS3

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
  <Code>InvalidObjectState</Code>
  <Message>The operation is not valid for the object's access tier</Message>
  <StorageClass>INTELLIGENT_TIERING</StorageClass>
  <RequestId>43XTDH6Q7E9F2N5J</RequestId>
  <HostId>3Fn/qzcZwOxaCg1LLDsczSXF7stl7sbOwwDR1ajHIc+guZgxAfFHm1WfRoXWEsFLWPJzKt9Ynaw=</HostId>
</Error>
```

So based on whether the request succeeds or not, I can determine whether to show the "download" or "restore" button for the item.

Comment: yes, but s3 intelligent tiering class should return the info regarding in which storage this object is right now or not!

Comment: @washiur17 Yes it should, but it doesn't.

Comment: What's the benefit of it over HEAD request?

Comment: @greatvovan When I originally asked the question, the information wasn't available in the HEAD response. HEAD is definitely the better way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a try catch. Try calling the restore and catch the exception. In your catch you can then do a GetObject.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to build a UI that lists the contents of the bucket and for each item, there will be either a download button or a restore button. So I don't actually want to restore anything until the user clicks the button.

Comment: Ok it seems that the list object result includes a key named StorageClass for each object. Is that not showing you the correct storage class? https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects_v2

Comment: It does, but the storage class is "Intelligent Tiering". Within that, there are multiple tiers: Frequent Access, Infrequent Access, Archive Access, and Deep Archive Access (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/storage-class-intro.html#sc-dynamic-data-access). The goal is to find out when the object is in one of the two archive tiers.

Comment: Ok just had a thought. Why not just a download button for all objects. I assume that is the ultimate goal here? For archived objects, you restore them to ultimately he able to download? So just abstract from the user whether it's archived or not. From the user's perspective they will just download the object. So when the user clicks download you then do the try catch. If the object is archived, you do a restore amd a download. You can even print a message to the screen to say "Please wait while the object is being restored" or something like that.

Comment: I think I have it figured out; if you attempt to do a GetObject for something that's archived, it will probably fail (it fails when it's in Glacier; I'm hoping IT-Archive behaves the same way). In your request, you can specify a byte range, so if I just ask for the first 10 bytes of a file, then it's almost the same as doing HeadObject.

Comment: well done. you should consider posting an answer and you might get some comments from other people who might have done something similar already.

Answer (score 1):

Likewise in HTTP HEAD request, it's now available in AWS CLI too.

```
aws s3api head-object --bucket xxxxxx --key input/2021-06-16-xxxxxx.xml
```

```
{
    "AcceptRanges": "bytes",
    "ArchiveStatus": "DEEP_ARCHIVE_ACCESS",
    "LastModified": "Wed, 16 Jun 2021 19:43:26 GMT",
    "ContentLength": 533096,
    "ETag": "\"d9a61a886e50199806664cdbd9xxxxxx\"",
    "VersionId": "null",
    "ContentType": "application/xml",
    "ServerSideEncryption": "AES256",
    "Metadata": {},
    "StorageClass": "INTELLIGENT_TIERING"
}
```

Official Docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/intelligent-tiering-managing.html