# If I use intelligent tiering, how do I know in which class my s3 object is atm?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am not clear, how do I know, which tier my object is, when I use "intelligent" tiering or is it just done under the hood and I am not able to see the class, that is used?

Comment: Use a HEAD request - https://stackoverflow.com/a/70966399/4800344. Marking as duplicate :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To determine the current access tier of an object in the Intelligent-Tiering storage class, you can use the Amazon S3 Inventory (1) report or the S3 Select Object Content API action (2). Or simply make a Head request (3).

1. Inventory report includes:
   **Storage class** – The storage class that's used for storing the object. Set to STANDARD, REDUCED_REDUNDANCY, STANDARD_IA, ONEZONE_IA, INTELLIGENT_TIERING, GLACIER, DEEP_ARCHIVE, OUTPOSTS, GLACIER_IR, or SNOW https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/storage-inventory.html
2. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_SelectObjectContent.html
3. Make a HEAD request on your objects to report the S3 Intelligent-Tiering archive access tiers. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_HeadObject.html